# Block discovery information

Tags: blockchain

Do blocks on the ethereum chain contain any information about who/what/where a block was discovered?

If so, where in the metadata is this information held?

Answer (score 1):

At best, you can get the *who*, if you are only referring to the `address` who mined the block. Any further information would undermine the privacy ethics of the blockchain.